# Reopen reviews not working, attempt to vote leave closed results in HTTP 500 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, reopen-review

In the *Review Reopen Votes* queue, attempts to vote "Leave closed" with any reason results in an *"An error occurred when submitting your feedback. Please try again."*. When I check the network tab of the browser tools in my browser (Firefox 115.0.3 (64-bit) on Windows 11), I see a HTTP 500 response to the POST to `https://stackoverflow.com/review/leave-closed/<someid>` (where `<someid>` is an actual number). The response body (when viewed in the network tab) contains the HTML for the *"Oops! Something Bad Happened!"* page. I also tried in Microsoft Edge, and got the same result.

I reviewed reopen votes yesterday, and then it worked as expected. Other review queues seem to be unaffected (though I only checked *Close votes* and *Low quality answers*).

Comment: This just happened to me, here and on another SE site.

Comment: Heh - I ran into this on my very first review after an extended 'vacation' due to my participating in the "moderation/curation strike".

Comment: @AdrianMole I restarted yesterday, so I was surprised when it didn't work today ;)

Comment: Not working for me either.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We're seeing the errors on our end. We'll update when we have more info.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for reporting! And my apologies, while fixing another bug I inadvertently broke the Reopen votes queue. Basically, we were grabbing the review task to validate permissions, but at that point we only grabbed the task id, so when I tried to reference the post id in the permissions check, ...there was no post id. Thus everyone's favorite error: the NRE. I am deploying a fix right now so it should be live within the next 30 minutes or so. Let me know if you're still seeing any issues.

Comment: I thought stack overflows were our favourite errors.

Comment: err, right! that's a given. this is, of course, my second favorite.

Comment: I can confirm it works again. Thanks for fixing!

Comment: NPE/NRE's and stack overflows are so basic. I am very partial to a SolarFlareException. I really hope that there is software floating out there in outer space which can throw such an exception.

Comment: @Gimby I wonder what the exception looks like, and in which direction it’s thrown. Is it spherical? Cyllindrical? Rectangular?