# Unable to edit my own answers, attempt save edits results in server 500 error

Tags: bug, edits

For the past couple of days I've occasionally not been able to edit my own answers and receive a server 500 error. The result is similar to this [issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425890/8690857) with viewing reviews.

Making a POST request to `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postId>/edit-submit/<GUID>` and receive back a server 500 error with the same HTML response with "Oops! Something Bad Happened - Stack Overflow". Tried also in Safari and Chrome on Android device with same result.

- Chrome 115
- macOS 12.6.3 (Monterey)

At some point a day or two later I can *finally* successfully edit the answers.

Comment: Possibly related: *[How can I avoid "An error occurred submitting the edit" error message? (working July 13th)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425430)*. See also [the linked pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/425430). There is also [a deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425486/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-hidden-oops-something-bad-happened). E.g., *"But the response is a 500"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah, definitely seems related. No solution reached though, other than waiting.